# Change desktop background to a solid color (e.g. pitch black) in GNOME 3

Tags: 16.04, gnome, ubuntu-gnome, desktop-background

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 with GNOME and I would like to set the background color to black.

If I right click in the background I can select a wallpaper or a photo or a color. But there are only a few colors available.

How can I open a palette and select the `#000000` color ?

Comment: It is so disappointing that this is not supported by default. Ubuntu's has degrated in the last 5 years.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### Simple solution

First create an all-black image (jpg or png) using **Gimp** for example and save it to a convenient location. Alternatively you may download one from the internet.

Then open **GNOME Tweak Tool** (aka *GNOME Tweaks*, you may have to install it first) and go to the '*Desktop*' section (or the '*Appearance*' section depending on your Ubuntu version). Look for '*Background Location*'. You can select the image you created/downloaded to load as the desktop background.

[image: setting background image in GNOME Tweaks]

### Advanced alternative

**GUI way:**

1. Launch **dconf Editor** either from your application list or using `dconf-editor` command (you may have to install it first).
2. Go to `/org/gnome/desktop/background/`.
3. Select '*picture-options*'.
4. Disable *Use default value* and select **'none'** in the '*Custom value*' option.
5. Get back to `/org/gnome/desktop/background/` and select '*primary-color*'.
6. Disable '*Use default value*' and put the hex-code for your colour, e.g. `#000000` for pitch black in the '*Custom value*' box.

**CLI way:**
You can achieve steps 1-4 of the "GUI way" by running the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'none'
```

in Terminal and then steps 5 & 6 by running the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color '#000000'
```

Comment: The CLI commands worked fine.

Comment: +1 for the CLI commands on Ubuntu 23.04. Worked like a charm!

Comment: Ubuntu 22. CLI way works!

Answer (score 1):

CLI way worked but I did need to right-click desktop and then select a solid background, which wasn't available before.

Answer (score 0):

### Solid and Gradient Wallpaper

- Use Open Office Draw to create a solid or gradient background.
- Export the .odg file to the "Pictures" folder as a .png or .jpg file.
- Right click the file in the "Pictures" folder and select `Set as Wallpaper`

[image]

[image]