# How can I change the 15 predefined background colors on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, colors, desktop-background

In Ubuntu 18.04 via **Settings > Background > Colors** I can choose one of the 15 predefined solid background colors. Can I select these 15 colors myself?

The suggested solutions show that my question isn't being understood:

1. I'm not talking about THE background color: take a look at **Settings > Background > Colors** in 18.04.
2. The "solution" of creating a solid color image has crossed my mind, but I think it is an overkill effort to circumvent the poor parametrisation (and therefore the implementation) of the issue.

Thanks

Comment: See if https://askubuntu.com/a/943251/248158 helps.

Comment: The suggestions above show that my question isn't understood: (1) I do not talk about THE background color: take a look at Settings/Background//Colors in 18.04 and then reply; (2) the "solution" of creating a solid color image has crossed my mind, but I think it is an overkill effort to circumvent the poor parametrisation (and therefore the implementation) of the issue.

Comment: Do not make clarifications in the comments. Please incorporate whatever you need in the question itself.

Comment: Dear pomsky, I have again looked at https://askubuntu.com/questions/943245/change-background-color-to-pitch-black, but I also do not like the second suggestion there: (1) the contexts -16.04 versus 18.04- are different, i.e. 1 versus 15 background alternatives,  and (2) tweaking and pooking around in files of the system  should be an exceptional affair and not something one needs to do for having the flexibility of choosing the colors one prefers.

Comment: The developers of 18.04 did a great job by introducing a global interactive tool for the setting of all kinds of options/parameters/variables. I hope that the interactive selection of colors is on their to-do-list.

Comment: Dear Pomsky, I know that with the RGB-scheme one has 16777216 different colors: the 1 versus 15 I am talking about is the following: in ubuntu 18.04 the user has the interactive choice between 15 PREDEFINED solid colors for the background. I would like to define these alternatives myself (by choosing for each of them one of the 16777216 colors).

Comment: Dear pomsky, the issue can indeed be reduced to a single one: how to select interactively a color in ubuntu. I suppose the offer of a predefined selection of 15 alternatives in Ubuntu 18.04 is only a temporary alternative for letting users interactively select the color(s) they like.

Comment: Yep, I have been trying to suggest a way to do exactly that. Here's a CLI way: first running `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'none'` *only once*, and then using the following command one can achieve any custom coloured background: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color '#XXXXXX'` (`#XXXXXX` stands for the hexcode of the preferred colour).

Comment: Dear pomsky, if I experiment a bit with a LAZERUS-application I can indeed select the backgroundcolor I want; with the help of your procedure I can then install it in ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: In that case it's covered by the other question, better to mark it as a duplicate of the other so that your question will work as a sign  post :)

Comment: Dear pomsky, I do not agree. Yes, there is a way to set THE background color (by entering instructions via a terminal window). My original question however remains unanswered! As does the fundamental issue: the interactive selection of colors in ubuntu (in the spirit of the  interactive setting of parameters,variables,... in 18.04). It is time to limit the old way (terminal instructions) to a minimum. Hanging on to it is incompatible with the promotion of user-friendliness and productivity.